# ASP.NET Webforms - Dynamic Text Box/Labels fails 508 compliance

Tags: xslt, dynamic, webforms, panel, section508

I have Webform Panel that contains dynamic fields created using XSLT transformation using the below logic.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8574/Generate-dynamic-ASP-NET-pages-by-using-XML-and-XS

Config File: (example as in above link)

XSLT: (example as in above link)

508 compliance fails for those fields. Rather than writing the dynamic field's label directly in the form, I tried using the below, but it still not 508 compliant.

```
<asp:label runat="server">
  <xsl:value-of select="@label" />                
</asp:label>
```

Any leads/help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal XSLT and input XML example that gives the (wrong) result, and the expected corrected result. Just saying that something unseen is not 508 compliant it too wide a requirement to give a helpful answer. Have a look at [faq] and [ask] if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. Example of XML and XSLT used are similar to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8574/Generate-dynamic-ASP-NET-pages-by-using-XML-and-XS

Comment: "Similar" doesn't help. Please show a minimal example of the part that fails and the actual result that you would like to have. I'm sorry, but we can't guess at what you are trying to achieve. Try to be precise, succinct and complete.